# Meteor Iron Router data from params on click

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm passing a data context through Iron Router to the page. I can call it with this._id.

But when you have a click event on element within an each loop via spacebars, it changes 'this' to that object I just clicked. Which totally makes sense.

However, how would I grab some properties from the element I just clicked but also get params info I defined from the router?

For example if I had a list of posts:

```
{{#each posts}}
  <li class="post-title">{{title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

And I click those elements listed:

```
'click .post-title': function(){
  console.log(this) //this will be the _id of the post I clicked.

 var new_object = {
   title: this.title,  //from that object I want that title
   page_url: // But here I want the params data I defined in the router //
 }
}
```

If it wasn't a click event, I could just say, this._id...but as you can see in this instance I can't. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I could set it to the Session but there's got to be another way for me to access the template data context within a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data of the current route like so:

```
'click .post-title': function(){
  var data = Router.current().data();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: This does not work in iron:router 1.0.12, I had to use `Router.current().params`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

Say that your page is in client/views/posts/post_item.html and inside it you have:

```
<div class="post-title">
  Something To Click On
</div>
```

Your JS file for this would be in client/views/posts/post_item.js and inside it:

```
 'click .post-title': function() {
    Router.go('postEdit', {_id: this._id});
  }
```

The `{_id: this._id}` part is how you pass to Iron Router the _id of the post that you clicked `.post-title` in. Iron Router needs things to be passed in as a hash / key-value.

And then in the router.js:

```
  this.route('postEdit', {
    path: '/posts/:_id/edit',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
```